# Load text from csv file with int and float columns into ndarray

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv, numpy

I have csv file as input :

```
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
```

It has mix of int and float.
when i tried to import file using "numpy.loadtext" what i got is 2d array with every column as float.

```
r = np.loadtxt(open("text.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=0)
```

and i received **output** like :

```
array([[   6.   ,  148.   ,   72.   , ...,    0.627,   50.   ,    1.   ],
       [   1.   ,   85.   ,   66.   , ...,    0.351,   31.   ,    0.   ],
       [   8.   ,  183.   ,   64.   , ...,    0.672,   32.   ,    1.   ],
       ...,
       [   5.   ,  121.   ,   72.   , ...,    0.245,   30.   ,    0.   ],
       [   1.   ,  126.   ,   60.   , ...,    0.349,   47.   ,    1.   ],
       [   1.   ,   93.   ,   70.   , ...,    0.315,   23.   ,    0.   ]])
```

which is perfect have 2d array with each row in list instead of tuple.
but when looking into datatypes every column treated as float which is not correct.

What i am asking is there any way i can do output like :
**Desired output**

```
array([[   6   ,  148   ,   72   , ...,    0.627,   50   ,    1   ],
       [   1   ,   85   ,   66   , ...,    0.351,   31   ,    0   ],
       [   8   ,  183   ,   64   , ...,    0.672,   32   ,    1   ],
       ...,
       [   5   ,  121   ,   72   , ...,    0.245,   30   ,    0   ],
       [   1   ,  126   ,   60   , ...,    0.349,   47   ,    1   ],
       [   1   ,   93   ,   70   , ...,    0.315,   23   ,    0   ]])
```

I did tried this approach:

```
r = np.loadtxt(open("F:/idm/compressed/ANN-CI1/Diabetes.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=[('f0',int),('f1',int),('f2',int),('f3',int),('f4',int),('f5',float),('f6',float),('f7',int),('f8',int)])
```

**Output**

```
array([( 6, 148,  72, 35,   0,  33.6,  0.627, 50, 1),
       ( 1,  85,  66, 29,   0,  26.6,  0.351, 31, 0),
       ( 8, 183,  64,  0,   0,  23.3,  0.672, 32, 1),
       ( 1,  89,  66, 23,  94,  28.1,  0.167, 21, 0),
       ...,
       ( 1, 126,  60,  0,   0,  30.1,  0.349, 47, 1),
       ( 1,  93,  70, 31,   0,  30.4,  0.315, 23, 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4','<i4'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', '<i4'), ('f8', '<i4')])
```

Here you can see dtype solve the problem but now its not in correct form which i require,
**[[col1,col2,...,coln],] instead of [(col1,col2,...,coln),] ndarray**

Thanks

**------------------EDIT------------------------**
problem why i am asking is that I am giving this 2d array as input to my binary classification network, when all values are int and in [[ ]] shape it's converging to values , but in current case it's mixed output is either 0. or 1. with very high error learning.
Visit https://github.com/naitikshukla/MachineLearning/blob/master/neural/demo_ann.py!
for complete code

In input space if i mark my current input and unmark from line 69-88 then output will be both 0 and 1.

So i wanted to change it to correct datatype and see if that will solve my issue.

There are very good explanation below for this not possible , i will see any workaround and see if i can use current input for train and predict.

Comment: Why do you need exactly this form? The `(...)` are the result of your object array, I think. It might be easier to change the next command in which your expecting difficulties with this format.

Comment: I am trying to build code for single layer neural network with Backpropagation, so this is suppose to be starting step for me , next step what i am doing is obviously split and then call train and predict,
`train, test = train_test_split(scale_inp, test_size = 0.25)  #split data into test and train` and then `train_X = np.array(train[:,0:8])`.
If i will be able to do these i think again in train dot product will cause problem for me.

Comment: In the network case, what's important about integers versus floats?  Put long additions in an edit rather than a comment.  It's easier to read there. For training/testing split, is this by column or row?  Does the integer v float matter?

Comment: Can the learning code handle a compound dtype like this?

Comment: I have to check if other than [[ ]] if it can work with other dtype particularly [( )] , but very less hope for that i think because of dot product in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to create a numpy array like [[col1,col2,...,coln],] which containing different types of values.

numpy array is **homogeneous**. In other words, numpy array contains only values of one single type.

```
In [32]: sio = StringIO('''6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
    ...: 1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
    ...: 8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
    ...: 1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0''')

In [33]: r = np.loadtxt(sio, delimiter=",", skiprows=0)
In [34]: r.shape
Out[34]: (4, 9)
In [41]: r.dtype
Out[41]: dtype('float64')
```

This above line create a 2D array of floats, and it's shape is 4x9.

```
In [36]: r = np.loadtxt(sio, delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=[('f0',int),('f1'
    ...: ,int),('f2',int),('f3',int),('f4',int),('f5',float),('f6',float),('f7'
    ...: ,int),('f8',int)])
In [38]: r.shape
Out[38]: (4,)
In [45]: r.dtype
Out[45]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', '<i4'), ('f8', '<i4')])
```

This line code create a 1-D [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). Each element of this array is a structure that contains 9 items. It's still homogeneous.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you get a 2d array of floats.  In the second, a 1d array with a structured dtype, a mix of ints and floats.  What where columns in the first are now named fields.  The structured records are marked with () instead of the [].

Both forms are valid and useful.  It just depends on what you need to do.

The structured form is more useful when some of the fields are strings or other things that don't fit the integer/float pattern.  Usually you can work with the integers as floats without any loss of functionality.

What exactly is wrong with the first case, the all floats?  Which is most important - named columns, or ranges of columns (e.g. 0:5, 5:8)?